# FullCalendar overlay doesn't show correct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi I'm using the fullCalendar plugin to display a calendar. In that I have an overlay 'window' that is activated whenever one hover over an object. It display extra information such as location and description of that element.

And it works fine with the original calendar settings and data and with the regular day, week and month views. But I also wan't to create a functionality that removes the weekends and only shows a work week(monday-friday).

I have decided to do this by destroying the calendar and re-initialized it with new default settings(weekends:false) and render the events again. This is a function activated on a button click. And this is where the overlay starts failing. Depending on what I did before I clicked the button it either shows just an empty overlay or the information from whatever object I hovered over before I clicked the button. And therefore displays the same information no matter what object I hover over. Anyone has any inputs to what goes wrong and whether I could change something?

The overlay function:

```
$scope.overlay = $('.fc-overlay');
$scope.alertOnMouseOver = function( event, jsEvent, view ){
    $scope.event = event;
    $scope.overlay.removeClass('left right top').find('.arrow').removeClass('left right top pull-up');
    var wrap = $(jsEvent.target).closest('.fc-event');
    var cal = wrap.closest('.calendar');
    var left = wrap.offset().left - cal.offset().left;
    var right = cal.width() - (wrap.offset().left - cal.offset().left + wrap.width());
    var top = cal.height() - (wrap.offset().top - cal.offset().top + wrap.height());
    if( right > $scope.overlay.width() ) {
        $scope.overlay.addClass('left').find('.arrow').addClass('left pull-up')
    }else if ( left > $scope.overlay.width() ) {
        $scope.overlay.addClass('right').find('.arrow').addClass('right pull-up');
    }else{
        $scope.overlay.find('.arrow').addClass('top');
    }
    if( top < $scope.overlay.height() ) {
        $scope.overlay.addClass('top').find('.arrow').removeClass('pull-up').addClass('pull-down')
    }
    (wrap.find('.fc-overlay').length == 0) && wrap.append( $scope.overlay );
```

The buttonclick function:

```
/*remove weekends from calendar*/
$scope.removeWeekends = function (noWeekend) {
    $(".calendar").fullCalendar('destroy');
    $(".calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        height: 400,
        editable: true,
        weekends: noWeekend,
        weekNumbers: true,

        header:{
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver
    });

    $scope.renderAcademy($scope.academy);
    $scope.renderCourse($scope.events);
}
```

The last two functioncalls are just simple forloops that render the elements as:

```
$scope.renderCourse= function (data) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
            id: data[j].id,
            title: data[j].title,
            start:  data[j].start,
            end: data[j].end,
            className: data[j].className,
            editable: false,
            location: data[j].location,
            info: data[j].info
        }, true)
    }
};
```

Which actually brings up a little sidequestion: Can anyone explain why it works fine when I call those two functions in this order, but if I call the renderCourse function first, the second seemingly is never called?

Comment: What about using custom views? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/cd60uvd5/

Comment: I'm not sure that was working in the original initialization (See answer below). With the new initialization it should definitely work. But I can also easily set weekends true/false now so it's not necessary with that. It's more the overlay that is the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar already support the ability to hide weekends by setting the weekends to false.. There is no need for you to destroy/recreate the object

Change:

```
editable: true,
weekends: noWeekend,
```

To:

```
editable: true,
weekends: false
```

Comment: In general I wan't the weekends to be there. It's just on this one buttonclick I wan't them gone. And I at least haven't been able to change that weekends settings to false for that one function, without destroying/recreate. The calendar simply disappears when I try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know if anyone would even read this now that it is a few days old but here goes.

I've changed the way that the calendar was initialized from:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        weekNumbers: true,

        header:{
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        weekNumbers: true,

        header:{
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventMouseover: $scope.alertOnMouseOver
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" id="calendar"></div>
```

This, unlike the other way, lets me dynamically change values in the calendar options with something like this:

```
$scope.removeWeekends = function () {
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.weekends=false;
};
```

But the mouseOver overlay doesn't work at all now. Or it doesn't show anyting. It get's the value from the object because if I for instance hover over a button with a tooltip before one of the calendar object, it works but only shows the same object values for all the events.

The HTML for the overlay:

```
<div class="panel bg-white b-a pos-rlt">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <div class="h4 font-thin m-b-sm">{{event.title}}</div>
        <div class="line b-b b-light"></div>
        <div><i class="icon-calendar text-muted m-r-xs"></i> {{event.start | date:'medium'}}</div>
        <div class="ng-hide" ng-show='event.end'><i class="icon-clock text-muted m-r-xs"></i> {{event.end | date:'medium'}}</div>
        <div class="ng-hide" ng-show='event.location'><i class="icon-pointer text-muted m-r-xs"></i> {{event.location}}</div>
        <div class="m-t-sm">{{event.info}}</div>
      </div>
```